# Generate IPA files (iphone) on Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: flash, builder

I am just a newbie on Flash Builder 4.5, and some lads told me that i can generate IPA file in order to generate iPhone apps from it.
Is there a tutorial on the net to explain me how to ???
Same question for the Android market. Thanks

Gwenael

Answer (score 3):

Internet is full of tutorials:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-blackberry.html

For iOS, you will need to enroll in Apple's iOS Developer Program and access the Provisioning Profile for needed certificates.